# How to navigate using vim keybindings in command line mode?

Tags: command-line

When using vim in commandline mode, I have to navigate using only arrow keys. I can't use the native vim bindings because when I key `<esc>`, it exits commandline mode.

For example, if I was typing a command in commandline mode, `:w eiff.txt`, but I realised that I've made a mistake, it should have been `diff.txt`, if I try to go back with the `b` button, it doesn't work because I can't hit `<esc>`.

So is there any way to navigate using the vim keys in the command line mode?

Comment: I think as of now, you only exit command line mode when you press `control` + `C`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can type <kbd>q</kbd><kbd>:</kbd> to see command history and edit it like any other buffer.

Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> on the line with the command you want to execute.

p.s.: <kbd>q</kbd><kbd>/</kbd> works the same but for search history.

Comment: You can also use `<c-f>` while on the command line to bring up the command-line window. See `:h cmdwin` for more information

Comment: Alternatively, the plugin [`rsi.vim`](https://github.com/tpope/vim-rsi) by Tim Pope provides readline mappings for insert and command modes. I find it very handy for simple editing tasks.